# VSCode Debug Node app using Inspector protocol

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I am running node app using pm2 with `--inspect` flag. I am able to debug my app on the following url:

> chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@62cd277117e6f8ec53e31b1be58290a6f7ab42ef/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=local.abc.com:9003/node

How can I debug this application using VS Code built in debugger?

Answer (score 1):

If you have launched your node app from the command line create this "attach" launch config:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "name": "Attach",
    "port": 9222,
    "protocol": "inspector"
}
```

or let VS Code launch your app and attach to it in one go:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Program",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/your_app.js",
    "protocol": "inspector"
}
```

Comment: what is "pm2"? 
what does not work for you? any error message?

Comment: does it make a difference if you use the "9003" port (from the url) instead of the default "9222"?

Comment: Nope. pm2 is node application runner. I am able to debug my app in browser but not in vscode!